# Dynamically Generated Collapsible Menu using Navgoco

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, list, amazon-s3

My current program receives all objects stored in a directory in a S3 bucket. I then receive each object's key and url that are then used to create lists after a button press. An example of the output:

```
image
    someImage.png
    someOtherImage.jpg
other
    someWordDoc.doc
    someThing.txt
video
    someVideo
        HLS_1M.m3u8
        HLS_2M.m3u8
        HLS_400K.m3u8
        someVideo.mp4
```

What I am trying to do is use this output and create a collapsible list using the Navgoco plugin for jQuery. The collapsible part of the code works only when the HTML for the list is already created after loading. The code for the collapsible part:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Initialize navgoco with default options
    $("#demo1").navgoco({
    caretHtml: '',
    accordion: false,
    openClass: 'open',
    save: true,
    cookie: {
        name: 'navgoco',
        expires: false,
        path: '/'
    },
    slide: {
        duration: 400,
        easing: 'swing'
    },
    // Add Active class to clicked menu item
    onClickAfter: function(e, submenu) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#demo1').find('li').removeClass('active');
        var li =  $(this).parent();
        var lis = li.parents('li');
        li.addClass('active');
        lis.addClass('active');
    },
});

    $("#collapseAll").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#demo1").navgoco('toggle', false);
    });

    $("#expandAll").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#demo1").navgoco('toggle', true);
    });
});
```

What I what is for the collapsible part of the code to be called only when the newly generated list is complete, but my Javascript/jQuery skills are less then stellar. Is there a way for me to call the collapsible function only after the HTML is done generating?

Answer (score 0):

As long as it's in `$(document).ready(function () {` which it is, you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I know its a late response, But i too was searching for a answer for this and at last found a solution.

So Hope it will be useful for some one who find this.

You have to call the below code after you are sure that the data you are adding to the menu is loaded to the HTML. And be sure to remove from where it was there previously.

```
// Initialize navgoco with default options
    $("#demo1").navgoco({
    caretHtml: '',
    accordion: false,
    openClass: 'open',
    save: true,
    cookie: {
        name: 'navgoco',
        expires: false,
        path: '/'
    },
    slide: {
        duration: 400,
        easing: 'swing'
    },
    // Add Active class to clicked menu item
    onClickAfter: function(e, submenu) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#demo1').find('li').removeClass('active');
        var li =  $(this).parent();
        var lis = li.parents('li');
        li.addClass('active');
        lis.addClass('active');
    },
});

    $("#collapseAll").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#demo1").navgoco('toggle', false);
    });

    $("#expandAll").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#demo1").navgoco('toggle', true);
    });
```